# Background css image not showing

Tags: html, css

I have a link on my HTML page that I want like to display. The icon is not appearing and I'm not sure why. The image icon is located in a sub folder within my project and it can be found (double checked). I'm using the brackets IDE.

Html file:

```
  <div class="delivery"><a href="Delivery-Options.html">£2.99 Delivery >>More info</a></div>
```

Css file:

```
.delivery {
           float:left; width:59%; padding-left:48px;
           background:#ccc; background-image: url(images/delivery.jpg) 8px center;
          }
```

Comment: Where your css and image folder located in your folder?

Comment: Have you checked your code with web developers tool in Firefox or Chrome browser?

Comment: My html and css files are within the same folder, in that folder i have an images folder which contains the image i'm trying to show

Comment: I think 'background' might be overwriting your 'background-image'. Either have 'background-color' instead of just background or put it all in to 'background'

Comment: Yes sorry i should have mentioned that it works on no browser

Comment: Thankyou for the suggestion I tried this;

     .delivery{float:left; width:59%; padding-left:48px; background:#ccc 
      url(images/delivery.jpg) no-repeat 5px center;}

But it also doesn't work

Comment: I found your problem and changed my answer. that should work.

Answer (score 2):

`background-image` does not accept the shorthand you are using. Change to `background` instead.

As pointed out by @Gezzasa in the comment, using `background` shorthand will overwrite a previous `background-color`. Updated snippet shows both. Note that the colour should appear *after* the image.

```css
.delivery {
  float: left;
  width: 59%;
  padding-left: 48px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/200/300) #ccc;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 8px center;
}
```

```html
<div class="delivery"><a href="Delivery-Options.html">£2.99 Delivery >>More info</a></div>
```

Comment: that overwrites the background color

Answer (score 1):

You're using background position in your `background-image` param.

Remove that and put it in to `background-position`

ex: `background-position: 8px center; background-image: url(images/delivery.jpg);`

Answer (score 0):

This shows the image on left side as icon. You can change the background-size.

```
.delivery {
        width:59%; 
        padding-left:48px;
        background-size: 18px 18px;
        background-image:url(coffee.jpg) ;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

html

```
<div class="delivery"><a href="Delivery-Options.html">£2.99 Delivery >>More info</a></div>
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: @Rob i thought he wanted icon at the side of the link. so i tried this. this shows that image on left side of the link.

Comment: All you did was enter a bunch of CSS without explanation. SO is not a code writing service and no one learns from just blurting out markup or code.

Comment: I am new to this. Is it fine now @Rob ?

Comment: Better but explain how it moves the image to the left side. Don't assume he knows.